# Angular - certificate Error - net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID -

Tags: angular, get, frontend, certificate

we are developing a platform to be used for assistence, both Front End and Back End and we are getting the error "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" when calling the Back End service.

To be more specific, as front end we use Angular (v 12) that execute a GET to our back end (Java) that doesn't require any certificate for the authentication, since they are both on the same platform (OpenShift) and both are protected by a reverse proxy.

Our collegues working with angular tell us that we have this problem since the two domains where the FE and BE are exposed are not the same (ex. fe.my.network/be.other.network).

I'm not too convinced by this explanation because I've never had these problems while integrating other back end services.

I'm not an expert on the front end applications so, i'd like to know if this make sense to you all and if it's possible to resolve this Angular side, like trusting the certificate or bypassing it (we can't change the certificate which is essentially a CA).

Comment: You can't make your Angular app automatically trust the certificate, as this is a browser-based error. You have to trust the certificate browser by browser.

Comment: Ok, so there is no work around with angular, like with java. Not knowing how it works I supposed it could be possible to do something. unfortunately it's not possible to change the browser configurations since the platform is used by thousands of people and the configurations should be made in every single machine.

Comment: You'll need to set up a valid SSL certificate on the backend for it to work. Don't forget that Angular doesn't run on the server: it runs in the browser. Your users are making HTTPS requests from their machines, so you need a valid cert. I'm confident the explanation your colleagues gave you is wrong.